# MongoDB Aggregation - How can I" $lookup" a nested document "_id"?

Tags: mongodb

I successfully thanks to the help of the people here managed to $lookup two IDs in my document with their representive document in another collection. The next step I need to take is to further lookup a "nested" ID (refering to a document in another collection).

I tried to simply put another `$lookup` pipeline up but that just worked part-wise.
So it happens that an "empty" document was included into the `chieftain` attributes and all other attributes of `chieftain` where somewhat removed.

See my current aggregate:

```
db.getCollection('village').aggregate([
{
    "$match": { _id: "111" }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        from: "character",
        localField: "chieftainId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "chieftain"
    } 
},
{
     "$lookup": {
        from: "character",
        localField: "villagerIds",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "villagers"
    }
},
{
     "$lookup": {
        from: "bloodline",
        localField: "chieftain.bloodline",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "chieftain.bloodline"
    }
},
 { "$project" : { "villagerIds" : 0, "chieftainId" : 0}},
 { "$unwind" : "$chieftain" }
])
```

The result of that is the following:

```
{
    "_id" : "111",
    "name" : "MyVillage",
    "reputation" : 0,
    "chieftain" : {
        "bloodline" : []
    },
    "villagers" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "333",
            "name" : "Bortan",
            "age" : 21,
            "bloodlineId" : "7f02191f-90af-406e-87ff-41d5b4387999",
            "villageId" : "foovillage",
            "professionId" : "02cbb10a-6c0f-4249-a932-3f40e12d32c5"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "444",
            "name" : "Blendi",
            "age" : 21,
            "bloodlineId" : "b3a8ffeb-27aa-4e2e-a8e6-b382554f326a",
            "villageId" : "foovillage",
            "professionId" : "45dc9350-c84a-491d-a49a-524834dd5773"
        }
    ]
}
```

I expected the chieftain part to look like this (this is how the chieftain document looks like without the 'last' $lookup I added):

```
"chieftain" : {
        "_id" : "222",
        "name" : "Bolzan",
        "age" : 21,
        "bloodlineId" : "7c2926f9-2f20-4ccf-846a-c9966970fa9b", // this should be resolved/lookedup
        "villageId" : "foovillage",
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point of the lookup, `chieftan` is an array, so setting the `chieftan.bloodline` replaces the array with an object containing only the `bloodline` field.

Move the `{ "$unwind" : "$chieftain" }` stage to before the bloodline lookup stage so the lookup is dealing with an object.